# How to make a cardview layout with title stay on top of the borderline?

Tags: android, layout

I need to make a layout which look like this

[image]

Have been researched through alot of topic but still couldn't find out the way how to make it

If anyone have an idea or just a git source please give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

This is a vertical list of similar elements. So you can use Recyclerview for them. Inside an item you can use new Chip view (see https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f ).

Answer (score 0):

You can only set background color of cardview, cannot directly set border color. So, keep a drawable file for background as follows :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#abc" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can use the following layout to achieve the required style :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"><!--You can add your necessary content within this layout-->
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Sample Text"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use fieldset to achive that goal.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: sry - the question specifies Android XML layouts, not HTML